# In symfony what event can I use to add parameter to every database query?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I can’t find a solid answer for this, I’ve thought about using event listeners but I can’t seem to find a doctrine event to do what I want.

So the system we are building has different user accounts where each user is able to create a record, let’s say they can create a task using a Task entity and they can create a calendar event using a CalendarEvent entity.

Both entities have $createdBy mapped to the User entity.

When we pull data from the database, say a list of tasks, we only want the tasks for the current user but this would mean for every single entity in the system we would have to make sure the user is passed in the database query which easily becomes a mess.

What I want to do is automatically fill the $createdBy during persist and automatically add it as a where parameter during retrieval.

So instead in every repo function we write doing this for example:

$this->findBy([‘createdBy’=>$user]);

The createdBy part should be added automatically ; perhaps with some doctrine event?

Comment: You can use Doctrine filters for this. [example documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/filters.html)

Comment: [Filters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/filters.html#filters) are an easy approach though they are not quite what you asked for.  I'm not aware of any events that intercept queries.  You could probably make your own base repository class to override some of the basic find methods.  But honestly, I think you would be better off just making custom queries.

Comment: API Platform has Doctrine extensions to do exactly what you need (at least for the retrieval bit). I suppose you don't want to migrate to API Platform, but looking at the source code may be worth it, at least to understand how they do it: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#example.

As for the persist bit, a not so automatic workaround could be to add the user in the constructor.